# What is the correct syntax to include or exlude test assemblies in Visual Studio Tests with Visual Studio Team Services VSTS

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I have 2 test projects in my solution. I want to exclude one of them (with Selenium tests) to be excluded from the Visual Studio Test that is part of the continuous integration cycle.

The name of the generated dll is:

> Ta-Tend.UITests.dll

The option "Test assembly" (form the Test Execution Options) is:

> ***test*.dll; -:**\obj**; -***UITest*.dll

Whatever I fill in, the test is executed, while I need it to be excluded.
I cannot find anywhere the complete syntax definition for this field. Just parts of it, but they don't work.

Comment: Have you tried `*test*.dll; -:\obj**; -:***UITest*.dll` ?

Comment: A just did. The error I get: Preparing task execution handler.
Executing the powershell script: C:\a\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\1.0.77\VSTest.ps1


System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: The given path's format is not supported. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this code instead:

```
*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**;-:**\*UITest*.dll
```

If Ta-Tend.UITests.dll file is in the subfolder, using

`**\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**;-:**\*UITest*.dll`

Comment: Then there seems no test to match the filter: No test assemblies found matching the pattern: \*test*.dll;-:**\obj\\**\*;-:**\\*UITest*.dll

Comment: @Richard Is Ta-Tend.UITests.dll in the subfolder? I updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: The last option (in the subfolder) worked for me. Thanks.